# jQuery function working in Chrome, but not in IE

Tags: jquery

Company doesn't use HTML5, created the following workaround to allow use of the maxlength attribute for textareas. This works for Google Chrome, but doesn't work in Internet Explorer, any input would be appreciated, thanks! EDIT: I am using jQuery 1.6.2 and IE 11
UPDATE: After further troubleshooting, I have determined that IE is completely ignoring the jQuery function

```
$('textarea[maxlength]').keydown(function(){
    var limit = parseInt($(this.attr('maxlength')));
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.length > limit) {
      var new_text = text.substr(0, limit);
      $(this).val(new_text);
    }
});
```

Comment: try with simple `$('textarea').keydown(function(){`

Comment: `parseInt($(this.attr('maxlength')));` maybe my eyes deceive me, but this looks like it would break. It's probably just a typo, but it should be `parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));`

Comment: What errors do you get in IE and what versions of IE and jQuery are you using?

Comment: IE11 and jQuery 1.6.2. There are no actual errors on the IE side itself, it is just not correctly limiting the textareas to the maxlength. This works properly in Chrome

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9cz1wsvr/1/.

Comment: @Barmar are you sure?  Check the console: "this.attr is not a function" - it's working because [maxlength] is working.

Comment: Right. It should be `parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'))`.

Comment: How do you prevent IE11 from processing `maxlength` automatically?

Comment: I didn't have to, the JSP wouldn't even render without this function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the code, with the parentheses in the `parseInt` argument. It should be:

```
    var limit = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
```